# Google Maps doesn´t work on Galaxy s3 with 4.03

Tags: android, dictionary, ice

I am working on an AVD with the specs of a Galaxy S6. There I can use the `SupportMapFragment` without problems.

But when a customer tries to use the App including the Map on a Galaxy S3 Device with 4.9" and Android Version 4.03, the App doesn't show the Map.

What can I do?

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ibas.locatixteamviewer.MapsActivity">

<!--<Button-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/button1"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:background="#359c5e"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignParentTop="true"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"-->
    <!--android:padding="8dp"-->
    <!--android:layout_margin="5dp"-->
    <!--android:src="@drawable/menu_car_side_7_white"-->
    <!--android:textColor="#ffffff" />-->

</fragment>
```

//----------------------------

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you have ruled out signing key issues, you may be hitting the bug requiring phones to have `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission on some versions.

Comment: I have added this, but still it´s white... in the left buttom corner i see the Google Label in Map, but the Map stays white. What could be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like you have no internet connection, or the wrong signing key associated to your Google Maps account.

Comment: Failure found...Galaxy s3 doesn´t support the google Play Services...